# Problema com INotifyPropertyChanged C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, binding

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida, estou mexendo com c# WPF vs2017, e fiz o seguinte:
toda classe eu coloquei INotifyPropertyChanged e adicionei:

```
public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    void OnPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            this.PropertyChanged(
                this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
```

então fiz o "teste"  eu tenho 2 datagrid e 2 listas de serviços(1 com os serviços ja adicionados e outra disponivel para ser adicionado), então quando eu clico em um datagrid, ele adiciona esse serviço na outra lista e remove da lista de disponivel.
o problema é que não está atulizando sozinho, estou precisando utilizar novamente o comando de bind, segue o WPF

```
<DataGrid Name="GridListaDisponivel" 
                     Grid.ColumnSpan="20" 
                     Margin="5" 
                     Grid.RowSpan="7" 
                     Grid.Row="3"
                     CanUserAddRows="False"
                     CanUserReorderColumns="True"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                     SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                     SelectionMode="Extended"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListaServicoDisponivel, Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     SelectedValue="{Binding Path=Model, Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     IsReadOnly="True"
                     MouseLeftButtonUp="ListaServicoDisponivelOnMouseLeftClick"
              >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.2*" Binding="{Binding Codigo}" Header="Código"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.8*" Binding="{Binding Descricao}" Header="Descrição"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <Label Content="Serviços Cadastrados" Grid.ColumnSpan="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="11" Margin="-1,6,11,5"/>
    <DataGrid Name="GridListaCadastrado" 
                     Grid.ColumnSpan="20" 
                     Margin="5" 
                     Grid.RowSpan="7" 
                     Grid.Row="12"
                     CanUserAddRows="False"
                     CanUserReorderColumns="True"
                     AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                     SelectionUnit="FullRow"
                     SelectionMode="Extended"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CartaoBean.Model.ListaServico, Mode = TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                     IsReadOnly="True"
              >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.2*" Binding="{Binding Codigo}" Header="Código"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Width="0.8*" Binding="{Binding Descricao}" Header="Descrição"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Faltam detalhes para dar uma resposta mais precisa, como por exemplo que tipo de lista você está usando.

Vou assumir que você está adicionando `Servico` a uma lista `List<Servico>`.

Se for o caso, essa classe não notifica mudanças em sua coleção. Para obter o efeito desejado utilize `ObservableCollection<Servico>`.

Para maiores informações acesse o seguinte [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-create-and-bind-to-an-observablecollection)

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: obrigado pela resposta, a classe está sim ObservableCollection, então não poderia ser por isso que não está atualizando. Rodrigo